# Problem with firmware password

Tags: macbook-pro, security, password, firmware

Some days ago, I opened my laptop, it was doing security update. After the update, the login screen appeared and  I enter my regular user/password but instead of login it asked the firmware

Any idea why it asked firmware password?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  The way it's currently written, this looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Is there a specific problem you're trying to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Why is the system has detected the OS as being new. Perhaps you reset the NVRAM and exposed this or disk has failed and the OS doesn’t match the stored fingerprint or the hardware just happened to fail coincidentally to what actions you took. Firmware passwords don’t prompt until you try to boot to a non-designated OS. As long as the designated disk is fine, no password is needed.

The passcode is stored in the machine cryptographically and the specific model year dictates what your options are now.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455

As long as you have a screen different than the one above, you might have an activation lock, MDM lock or just FileVault situation and then you can use the normal erase and install or password reset mechanism which is much easier to recover.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202860

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have no idea why it has happened. I'm wondering to know how can I  boot to designed OS because I could not remember my firmware password.

Comment: No, I don’t have a way to bypass this short of the links and process above. @Mary